# how to create primary key and foreign key under one table. both primary key column and foreign key column must contain different values

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE Orders
-> (
-> O_Id int NOT NULL,
-> OrderNo int NOT NULL,
-> P_Id int,
-> PRIMARY KEY (O_Id),
-> FOREIGN KEY (P_Id)
-> );
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near    ')' at line 8

and after changing commands, it has given me this

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE Orders
-> (
-> O_Id int NOT NULL,
-> OrderNo int NOT NULL,
-> P_Id int,
-> PRIMARY KEY (O_Id),
-> CONSTRAINT fk_PerOrders FOREIGN KEY (P_Id)
-> REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
-> );
```

ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: Does the `Persons` table have a primary key column called `P_Id` ?

Comment: yes. actually, i want to display result from 3 tables, according to my project structure the second table (mentioned above) must contain both a primary key and foreign key column

Comment: Can you add the table description for your `persons` table? The usual suspects are: different column type and missing table.

Comment: Sorry guys for being late. The problem had solved , i had taken different column type in persons table .